# How to change text in a html table cell based on value in another cell

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have a HTML table with tens of columns and hundreds of rows. I want change the value of one table cell (TD) based on the value of another column. (I need to do it for three pairs of columns). Since I have no control over the data source, the order of columns may vary in some browsers.
Steps I've taken:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(j=0;j<2;j++){
        if(!!(JQ("div[DisplayName='"+updateViewerFields[i][j]+"']"))){
            updateViewer[i][j]=(JQ(this).find(JQ("div[DisplayName='"+updateViewerFields[i][j]+"']")).parent().index())+1;
    }}}
```

This stores the index location of the three fields in an array - 'UpdateViewer'. The Names of the three fields are coming in from 'UpdateViewerFields'.

```
var updateViewerFields=[["Phase 1","Phase 1 - Comments"],["Phase 2","Phase 2 - Comments"],["Phase 3","Phase 3 - Comments"]];
var updateViewer=[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]];
```

Now, I iterate through each row applying the formatting:

```
       JQ(this).find("tr").each(function(){
            //update data as per matrix
            for(i=0;i<3;i++){
               if(0!=updateViewer[i][0]){
                var currentPhaseElement= JQ(this).find(JQ('td:nth-child('+updateViewer[i][0]+')'));
              JQ(currentPhaseElement).attr('title',JQ(this).find(JQ('td:nth-child('+updateViewer[i][1]+')')).html());
//other stuff
    }
    }}
```

The code runs without error.However, the code is too slow in IE. I even get a warning when using IE -

```
'A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly. If it continues to run, your computer may become unresponsive. Do you want to abort the script?'
```

However, the same code runs smoothly in Chrome. How can I improve the code to achieve the same effect with faster response times in IE?
 PS> Please suggest changes to the code only.

Here is a fiddle representation: http://jsfiddle.net/QZs2G/7/

UPDATE: JQ in the code here is a variable to run jquery in noconflict mode.

```
var JQ=jquery.noconflict();
```

The fiddle uses the ubiquitous $ sign

Comment: setup a fiddle please.

Comment: Updated question with a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QZs2G/7/

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: *" I want change the value of one cell based on the value of another column."* care to explain what *cell*, what *column*, what *value*? What kind of attribute is *DisplayName* what's used for? Why don't you use `data-*` property for custom attributes? What's the desired result in your demo? What are you trying actually to achieve in your for loops? What are the array used for?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - try running the fiddle. A table cell signifies a normal TD whose properties are changing based on the other columns.
The code works. But I need a better/optimized way of achieving the same result.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - Also, try reading the question in its entirety. All your questions have already been addressed in the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some of the optimizations that I found in two days:

- IE processes Javascript slower than Chrome. Also, Javascript "for
  loop" is faster than Jquery "each". If a lot of data needs to be processed, you're better off doing all manipulations using a "for" loop instead of using the shortcut of Jquery "each" -
  [jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/4](http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/4)
- DOM manipulation is quite expensive. It needs to be kept to a
  minimum. Try to make all DOM changes in one go. However, that may not
  be possible in all cases.
- Manipulating DOM using Jquery needs to be
  done carefully. If there are a lot of changes required, you might as well create a copy of the element, edit it, and then add it to the DOM.
  http://api.jquery.com/clone/

  http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/
- Document fragments - Instead of adding small pieces to the DOM in
  steps, its much better to create a Document fragment and then add it
  to the DOM in one go.
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment

You can read more in this article.
 http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/

The steps mentioned here helped me reduce the load times of my pages significantly. I hope these practices help other HTML/Javascript developers as well.